# drawViewHierarchyInRect printing all black image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimage, ipod

I have a web view that I am trying to print and when i load a webpage that is long (more than a page) it prints out all black.  I cannot use the renderInContext method because it crashes the app because of high memory issues when i try to print a page.  I am using a dymo receipt printer.

Here is the code that i have

```
+ (UIImage*)viewToImage:(UIView*)theView
{
    UIImage *image = nil;

    // Save current bounds so we can reset them laster
    CGRect tmpFrame = theView.frame;
    CGRect tmpBounds = theView.bounds;

    // Adjust the bounds of the webview so we can take a screen shot of the entire view, even if its scrolled off screen.
    CGRect aFrame = theView.bounds;
    aFrame.size.width = theView.frame.size.width;
    aFrame.size.height = theView.frame.size.height;
    theView.frame = aFrame;
    aFrame.size.height = [theView sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    theView.frame = aFrame;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theView.bounds.size, NO, 1.8);

    [theView drawViewHierarchyInRect:theView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    // crashes the app [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```